# RarFile Python module error: rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool

Tags: python, unrar

I want to extract a RAR with rarfile python module:

```
import rarfile

rar_path = r'C:\...\Test.rar'
rar_password = '123'


# rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL = r'path to what .exe? I cant find it, is this line necessary?'
rar = rarfile.RarFile(rar_path)
rar.extractall(pwd=rar_password)
rar.close()
```

I get this error:

```
rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool
```

I already did what google says: I installed unrar, added it to PATH correctly and restarted my IDE

I also added WinRar to PATH just in case

I suppose that the error means that is searching for that unrar tool, so I guess I need to do:

```
rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL = r'some path to the unrar exe tool'
```

but what exe? I cant find any documentation for the "UNRAR_TOOL"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say that you installed unrar, and added it to your PATH - so how could you possibly not know what its path is?  What *did* you add to the PATH?

Comment: I don't know much about PATH but I followed this: https://youtu.be/0pU54jvv6bA?t=389